# How to use get default method on a selection field based on condition odoo 12?

Tags: odoo

What im trying to do is fetching a element from the selection field based on the state of the record.

```
@api.model
    def _get_next_step(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.state == 'draft':
                return rec.write({'next_step': 'waiting_room'})
            elif rec.state == 'waiting_room':
                return rec.write({'next_step': 'start_consultation'})
            elif rec.state == 'start_consultation':
                return rec.write({'next_step': 'finish_consultation'})

next_step = fields.Selection([
        ('waiting_room', 'To Waiting Room'),
        ('start_consultation', 'Start Consultation'),
        ('finish_consultation', 'Finish Consultation'),
        ('follow_up', 'Follow-Up'),
    ], string='Next Step', copy=False, index=True, track_visibility='onchange', defult='_get_next_step')
```

what i tried to do here is that,applying default in the selection field and wrote a function for the default method,But the field next_step is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default execution environment will never have records, `self` is always an empty recordset. The `api.model` decorator is telling you that already.

You could just change the field `next_step` to a computed field and trigger the recomputation on `state`. When you store the computed field, everything like searches/grouping will work like on normal fields.

Comment: what im trying to do is, to the corresponding state i need to update the selection field in the next step